# powershell sqlps databases doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Really weird issue with SQL PS provider where after a computer restart it cannot access the databases folder. Even though it appears in the ls!

I know that this does fix itself if I go into SSMS and connect to that server,  then it seems to fix itself until the next restart but I need this to be automated. Any ideas on how to make this work reliably from a restart?

I also think that it is ok if I close and start a new powershell session. But as the only repro is a restart it is quite disruptive to troubleshoot.

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> cd sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com
PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com> ls

Instance Name
-------------
DEFAULT

PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com> cd default
PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default> ls
Audits
AvailabilityGroups
BackupDevices
Credentials
CryptographicProviders
Databases
Endpoints
JobServer
Languages
LinkedServers
Logins
Mail
ResourceGovernor
Roles
ServerAuditSpecifications
SystemDataTypes
SystemMessages
Triggers
UserDefinedMessages


PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default> cd databases
cd : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default\databases' because it does not exist.
    At line:1 char:1
    + cd databases
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\sql\...fault\databases:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
       xception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Tried turning on debug messages but didn't give any more information

```
PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default> $debugpreference = 
'continue'
PS SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default> cd databases
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-
dev.myco.com\default\databases
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default\databases
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default\databases
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql
DEBUG: ItemExists: SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default\databases

cd : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\sql\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\default\databases' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd databases
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\sql\...fault\databases:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Any idea's or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: I thought 
    (get-item "sqlserver:\SQL\sql.ds-dev.myco.com\DEFAULT").Refresh();
Might do it but it didn't..

Comment: Interestingly it seems that "Get-ChildItem Databases -force" does work.. just Get-Location still doesn't

Comment: I've started assuming that weird, inexplicable behavior calls for running `sfc`. Also, paste the output of $psversiontable into your question, and paste the output of `(get-module -Name sqlserver).Version` into your question.